# Marshalling Guava Optional Class Object in Apache Camel

Tags: json, apache-camel, json-deserialization

I would like to marshal/unmarshal Optional Class Object data in camel. For example, the flow is as follows

```
from("rabbit:x")
     .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
     .process(new Processor() {
             public void  processor(Exchange exchange) {
             });
```

In the above route, in rabbit:x, there is a json data, which contains Guava Optional Class object. I would like to unmarshal it.

Please help me to add Guava Module([link](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava)) to serialize/deserialize Optional object. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upcoming Apache Camel 2.15 release you can more easily add custom Jackson modules to Camel.

So in Java code you do

```
JacksonDataFormat jackson = new JacksonDataFormat();
jackson.addModule(new GuavaModule());
```

And then use `jackson` in the route

```
 .unmarshal(jackson)
```

Its documented here: http://camel.apache.org/json